# Generate modal pop up with dynamic data from button click on table row

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Maven/Spring Boot/Thymeleaf project where I want a button click in a row to trigger a modal pop up that has a detail view of that row's data.

My original problem was that when a button was clicked on any given row, the modal pop up would ONLY display the first row's data. I realized this was because every button in every row had the same data-target, and the browser was grabbing the first row in the table.

So, now I'm trying to use JavaScript/jQuery to populate the modal's data for me. I've removed the data-target for the button so it doesn't trigger the default and incorrect behavior. For now, I've been trying to simply display the title of a book in a input text field. It has not worked. The modal pop up displays with the text field, but it's empty, and doesn't have the title from that particular row.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Book Note Book</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index_styles.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#myButton').on('click',function(){
      $("#myModal").modal("show");
      $("#txttitle").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent);
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Books</h2>
  <p>This is all the books you've read</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Date read</th>
        <th>More</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:if="${books.empty}">
            <td colspan="2"> No Books Available </td>
      </tr>
      <tr th:each="book : ${books}">
        <td><p th:text="${book.title}"/></td>
        <td><p th:text="${book.author}"/></td>
        <td><p th:text="${book.dateRead}"/></td>
        <td><button type="button" id="myButton" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td><p><b>Title</b></p></td>
                      <td><input type="text" id="txttitle"/></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `jquery` for this. Your first option was correct, you just were missing some tools. You can use on your button `th:attr="data-target=${book.title}"` and on your modal, change it's id like `<div class="modal fade" th:id="${book.title}" role="dialog">`.

This way, you will set the right target for each button and you don't need to add any unnecessary code. Of course, this is an example, but you can use whichever unique value you want for your target or id. In the end, you code would look something like this.

```
<tr th:each="book : ${books}">
    <td><p th:text="${book.title}"/></td>
    <td><p th:text="${book.author}"/></td>
    <td><p th:text="${book.dateRead}"/></td>
    <td><button type="button" th:attr="data-target=${book.title}" id="myButton" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></button>
    <div class="modal fade" th:id="${book.title}" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><p><b>Title</b></p></td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="txttitle"/></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: I thought this would work, but clicking the button now doesn't trigger the modal. I also removed the id="myButton" in case that was conflicting with the jQuery above, but clicking the button still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are the book titles unique? Also, can you check that data-target is being created correctly?

Comment: The book titles are unique. I'm honestly not sure how to check if the data-target is being created correctly.

Comment: Also, the button code should be `th:attr=data-target=${‘#’ + book.title}”`. I forgot the # in data-Target.